Synthesis of (Z)-alkenylboron reagent
Does anyone know the reaction mechanism between the hydroboration product of haloalkyne with organometallic reagents or 'KHB(Oi-Pr)3'? Additionally, does anyone know the reaction mechanism between organolithium reagent and vinylboronates?

